# ionic - make an event when slide menu closed

Tags: events, ionic-framework, menu, ionic3

My question is short and simple but I searched a lot about it and unfortunately I couldn't find the solution:

So, Is possible to make an event when slide menu has been closed and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [ionClose](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/menu/Menu/#output-events) event?

Output Events

```
ionClose    
Emitted when the menu has been closed.

ionDrag 
Emitted when the menu is being dragged open.

ionOpen 
Emitted when the menu has been opened.
```